# How to force sub-product-category to use the parent category template

Tags: template-hierarchy

I have this hierarchical Woocommerce products categories:

```
Parent X
    - child X1
    - child X2
Parent Y
    - child Y1
    - child Y2
```

I have products in each sub category and no product have more than one sub category.

I need to display products of `parent Y` in a view different from that of `Parent X`

I tried to create `taxonomy-product_cat-parent-x.php` and `taxonomy-product_cat-parent-y.php`

But it didn't work

I found the solution in [this article](http://werdswords.com/force-sub-categories-use-the-parent-category-template) for categories, and in the comments I found the below code for taxonomies, but it is untested according to the writer, and it didn't work with me:

```
/**
 * Filter the taxonomy hierarchy to inject a parent level of templates.
 * 
 * @param string $template The current template.
 * @return string Filtered taxonomy template.
 */
function new_tax_hierarchy( $template ) {
    $term = get_queried_object();

    // If not an object, or the object doesn't have a taxonomy, bail.
    if ( ! is_object( $term ) || ! isset( $term->taxonomy ) )
        return $template;

    $taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;

    // If the taxonomy isn't hierarchical, bail.
    if ( ! is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy ) )
        return $template;

    $templates = array();
    $parent_id = $term->parent;

    if ( 0 == $parent_id ) {
        // Use default values from get_taxonomy_template().
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy-{$term->slug}.php";
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy.php";
        $templates[] = 'taxonomy.php';
    } else {
        $parent = get_term( $parent_id, $taxonomy );

        // Current templates.
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy-{$term->slug}.php";
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy.php";

        // Parent templates.
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy-{$parent->slug}.php";
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy-{$parent->term_id}.php";
        $templates[] = 'taxonomy.php';
    }
    return locate_template( $templates );
}
add_filter( 'taxonomy_template', 'new_tax_hierarchy' );
```

Comment: http://werdswords.com/force-sub-categories-use-the-parent-category-template/

This is what I am looking for, it is for categories, but I need it for taxonomy (product_cat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, after facing these 2 issues:
1- use `template_include` in filter instead of `taxonomy_template`

2- I reordered these lines according to my need.

```
// Current first
$templates[] = "category-{$category->slug}.php";
$templates[] = "category-{$category->term_id}.php";

// Parent second
$templates[] = "category-{$parent->slug}.php";
$templates[] = "category-{$parent->term_id}.php";
$templates[] = 'category.php';
```

So here is my final code:

```
/**
* Filter the taxonomy hierarchy to inject a parent level of templates.
* 
* @param string $template The current template.
* @return string Filtered taxonomy template.
*/
function new_tax_hierarchy( $template ) {

    $term = get_queried_object();

    // If not an object, or the object doesn't have a taxonomy, bail.
    if ( ! is_object( $term ) || ! isset( $term->taxonomy ) )
        return $template;

    $taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;

    // If the taxonomy isn't hierarchical, bail.
    if ( ! is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy ) )
        return $template;

    $templates = array();
    $parent_id = $term->parent;

    if ( 0 == $parent_id ) {
        // Use default values from get_taxonomy_template().
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy-{$term->slug}.php";
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy.php";
        $templates[] = 'taxonomy.php';
    } else {
        $parent = get_term( $parent_id, $taxonomy );

        // Parent templates.
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy-{$parent->slug}.php";
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy-{$parent->term_id}.php";
        $templates[] = 'taxonomy.php';

        // Current templates.
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy-{$term->slug}.php";
        $templates[] = "taxonomy-$taxonomy.php";
    }

    return locate_template( $templates );
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'new_tax_hierarchy' );
```